# No value given for one or more required parameters. error during Search

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to search the data in a simple access database. The code is this

```
Call connect()
con.Open()
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * from PO_Record_Table where Customer=asd", con)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
While dr.Read
    MsgBox(dr(1))
End While

con.Close()
```

If I press search button, the error: No value given for one or more required parameters
comes on this line

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

The record "asd" is in the database customer field as a text type.
Why does this error come and how to finish this search without error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that the error is in the text `asd`  passed as value for the customer name

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * from PO_Record_Table where Customer='asd'", con)
```

Putting it in single quotes allows the db engine to recognize it as a string value to check against the `Customer` column name. Without quotes it is interpreted as the name of a parameter that you haven't passed to the command.

**EDIT** In your comment below you try to pass, as value for the Customer column, the content of a textbox but you forget to add the quotes around your textbox text value.

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * from PO_Record_Table where Customer='" & textbox.text & "'", con)
```

However, **this should never be done using the string concatenation method**, but always with the parameterized approach

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * from PO_Record_Table where Customer=@custName", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custName", Txt_Find.Text)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
.....
```

This is the only good method to query a database passing a command text with values obtained by user input. This method allows your code to be safe from [SQL Injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and remove problems in parsing the content of the textbox. Infact, without a parameter and if your textbox contains a single quote, the string concatenation method would fail with a syntax error.

Comment: The error comes again if I do this

any help on how to solve?
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * from PO_Record_Table where Customer=" & Txt_Find.Text, con)

Comment: Again, when you want to check the value of a column of type text against a known value you need to encapsulate the value inside a couple of single quotes. But wait a minute and I will update with a more precise answer

Comment: You have answered the second one aswell. Thankyou steve.
Also I will learn the new method soon

Answer (score 2):

No value given for one or more required parameters Error comes When your Tablename or filed name not exist , check `PO_Record_Table` and `Customer` spelling from your database

Comment: Thank you Imran. That is a common error so I always copy paste names now. It is not that one

Comment: One Possibility is also said by @Steve, try this also