# No given value for one or more required parameters when deleting a row

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to delete a row from my database, When I click to a row then press then my delete button it says that "No given value for one or more required parameters", I don't whats the error, I checked my table name and it's correct. My other delete button works fine

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this user?",
           "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string sql = string.Format(@"DELETE FROM User_list WHERE ID ={0}",
                dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            crudTools.ExecuteQuery(sql);
            crudTools.FillDataGrid("SELECT * FROM User_list", ref dataGridView2);}
```

Comment: When you put a breakpoint on that ExecuteQuery line, what's the value of the sql variable?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems originated from this query string inside `string.Format`:

```
string sql = string.Format(@"DELETE FROM User_list WHERE ID ={0}", dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

*No given value for one or more required parameters* indicates that the passed value in `WHERE` clause isn't valid, what you need to do if the `ID` is a string column just add single quotes around first parameter marked with `{0}`, because `dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()` returns a string but without any single quotes enclosure it will be treated by Access as numeric value:

```
string sql = string.Format(@"DELETE FROM User_list WHERE ID = '{0}'", dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

Or if the `ID` is an integer column, convert it to `int` before passing:

```
string sql = string.Format(@"DELETE FROM User_list WHERE ID = {0}", Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
```

NB: Remember to use parameterized query if the value comes from user input inside `DataGridView`.

Similar issue:

[No value given for one or more required parameters. error during Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722791/no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters-error-during-search)

Comment: I already tried your both codes, but it
     string sql = string.Format(@"DELETE FROM User_list WHERE ID = '{0}'", dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());

and the Convert.ToInt32 code
but the result is same

Comment: What value returned by `dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value`? The error states that you've missing one argument in `WHERE` clause and I think the potential query to break in your code is only that line, are you sure the execution flow breaks in `crudTools.ExecuteQuery(sql)`?